# Using the method of an object in an ArrayList in an if statement

Tags: if-statement, arraylist, syntax

I'm trying to use a method from an object in an ArrayList, that's a parameter of a method... I'm not sure what the syntax is. It's the condition of the if where the problem is. It's not supposed to be Ship, but what else? .getSize() is a method in the Ship class. Or maybe this solution is totally off?

```
public void deployShips(char[][] board, ArrayList<Ship> fleet, int x, int y) {

            if (Ship.getSize() == 5) {
                int[] coordinate = coordinate(x, y);
                board[coordinate[0]][coordinate[1]] = '+';
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i have understand what you need the code should be this:

n = the index postion of the object you need to call

```
fleet.get(n).theMethodYouNeed();
```

or if you need to check the entire list:

```
for(Ship ship: fleet){
   if (ship.getSize() == 5) {
        int[] coordinate = coordinate(x, y);
        board[coordinate[0]][coordinate[1]] = '+';
   }
}
```